# mod_rewrite match encoded URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

In my Apache config I'd like to return 403 when a query string parameter contains a specific value. Everything works fine except when the client query string is encoded in hex. How do I get it to match without having to type out the literal hex string?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mykey=myval [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Then test it:

```
# Works fine, returns 403
curl -I 'http://localhost/?mykey=myval'

# Does not work, returns 200:
curl -I 'http://localhost/?mykey=%6d%79%76%61%6c'
curl -I 'http://localhost/?%6d%79%6b%65%79=%6d%79%76%61%6c'
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable remains %-encoded (as it is in the request), unlike the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, which is %-decoded.

However, on Apache 2.4 you can use an Apache expression with the `RewriteCond` directive to URL decode the `QUERY_STRING` before making the comparison. For example:

```
RewriteCond expr "unescape(%{QUERY_STRING}) =~ /mykey=myval/"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will now successfully match requests of the form `?mykey=myval`, `?mykey=%6d%79%76%61%6c` and `?%6d%79%6b%65%79=%6d%79%76%61%6c`.

You don't need the `L` flag when using `F`, since it is *implied*. The regex `^` is marginally more efficient than `.*` if you simply need to be successful for any URL-path (without actually matching anything).

Note that the regex `mykey=myval` matches that string anywhere in the query string, so it would successfully match `anymykey=myval` and `mykey=myvalany`, which may or may not be a problem. To remove that ambiguity and only match the "key=value" pair in the query string then you would need to use a regex like `(?:^|&)mykey=myval(?:&|$)` instead.

Comment: Very good use of `expr` directive

Comment: You're an Apache ninja, thx :) I'm curious, did the developers have a rationale for keeping the query string %-encoded for this scenario as opposed to `RewriteRule` having %-decoded? I realize keeping the value unescaped is the "true" value, but some "dummy proof" safeguards for web admins could help millions of people. Common scenario: site admin wants to block access to a URL and isn't aware that malicious users can trivially %-encode the query string to bypass the `RewriteCond`.